# Int/list of numbers into a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string of numbers as shown below. I then have a random number shown below that. If I wanted to check to see if the random number equaled a number in the string how would I go about doing that?

```
          public string[] List = { "5", "3","9" };

            int test = random.Next(1, 10);
```

Right now I have the following. All of it works for my script except for if (test == number), Test is the defined random and the number is what I am trying to figure out how to refer it to the config.List, which is the list of 5,3, and 9. As you cannot use a string and int in the same if statement.

```
         foreach (string number in config.List)
            {

                if (test == number)
                {
                    TSPlayer.All.SendSuccessMessage("counting count = {0} number = {1}", count, test);
                }

                if (test >= 5)
                {
                    int amount = 200;
                    int monsteramount = 303;
                    NPC npcs = TShock.Utils.GetNPCById(monsteramount);
                    TSPlayer.All.SendSuccessMessage("#5 exists! count = {0} number = {1}", count, test);
                    TSPlayer.Server.SpawnNPC(npcs.type, npcs.name, amount, args.Player.TileX, args.Player.TileY, 50, 20);
                    TSPlayer.All.SendSuccessMessage(string.Format("{0} has spawned {1} {2} time(s).", args.Player.Name, npcs.name, amount));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The text of your question implies that you want all the values from the list to be put in the string, but your example implies that you really just want to know whether the list contains a particular value. Which are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to make  list of numbers and have the second number bchosen from random(); and if it happens to equal one of the numbers in the list a defines command takes place.

Comment: You should not use a string to create a list of numbers if you still want them to behave as numbers. Use an array or a List<int> or something more close to the real datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you need to convert a `string` representation of an integer to an `int`.

You can convert a string to an int like this:

```
string str = "5";
int val = Convert.ToInt32(str);   // val will be 5.
```

If you can't trust your inputs (i.e., you can't be 100% sure that the string is a valid number), then you can use `Int32.TryParse` like this:

```
string str = "5";
int val;
if ( Int32.TryParse(str, out val) ) {
    // conversion was successful, val == 5
} else { 
    // conversion failed. 
}
```

Alternatively, you could convert the `int` to a `string`, which is most easily done like this:

```
int val = 5;
string str = val.ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

To get more specific, you need to either use the first approach, like this:

```
foreach (string number in config.List)
{
    var val = Convert.ToInt32(number);
    if (test == val)
    {
        // ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you need to use the second approach, like this:

```
foreach (string number in config.List)
{
    if (test.ToString() == number)
    {
        // ...
    }
    ...
}
```

One way or another, you have to make sure your types match up.

**UPDATE 2**

This is literally the code you have in your question, right now (combining the top part and the bottom part), with only one change, that should make this one single compile error go away:

```
public string[] List = { "5", "3","9" };

int test = random.Next(1, 10);

foreach (string number in config.List)
{
    if (test.ToString() == number)  // This is the line I changed
    {
        // do your thing
    }

    if (test >= 5)
    {
        int amount = 200;
        int monsteramount = 303;
        NPC npcs = TShock.Utils.GetNPCById(monsteramount);
        TSPlayer.All.SendSuccessMessage("#5 exists! count = {0} number = {1}", count, test);
        TSPlayer.Server.SpawnNPC(npcs.type, npcs.name, amount, args.Player.TileX, args.Player.TileY, 50, 20);
        TSPlayer.All.SendSuccessMessage(string.Format("{0} has spawned {1} {2} time(s).", args.Player.Name, npcs.name, amount));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to convert the string to a value, I tried using Convert.ToInt32(string), but I am trying to use a list of values not just 5, so for example I have the below, but the convert to int seems to only work for one number, not a list of numbers.

            public string[] List = { "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

            if (test != Convert.ToInt32(config.List))

Comment: `if (test == number)` is where your code doesn't compile, right? You're in a `foreach` loop, checking each item in the list one at a time. Right?

Comment: Yes, because number ( the string numbers) is a string that is not an int, I am trying to make the string of numbers an int value so that if m random number (test) is equal to one of the numbers in the list it will do a command, if not it ignores that and does a different one in an else statement.

Comment: Yes. So, you do:  `if (test.ToString() == number)`

Comment: Then I get an error because the random number converted to a string cannot have a comparison of == because the string that is my list of numbers is a string[], or as seen by my c# "Error 3 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string[]'"

Comment: Then you are not using the code you posted in your question. Because the code you posted in your question is comparing a `string` to an `int`.

Comment: The first comment you posted has you attempting to convert the entire list instead of just the element you are looking for. That is where this error is coming from. Don't start from that code. Start from the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Specifically, look at the difference between the code in my answer (`Convert.ToInt32(number)`) and the code in your comment (`Convert.ToInt32(config.List)`). See? The `config.List` variable is a string array. The `number` variable is a single string.

Comment: I am using the code from my question
public string[] List = { "5", "3","9" };
I am trying to get the random number (test) to check with the List to see if it is equal to a number in the list and then do a command if it does match a number in the command.
I apologize for the misleading, I did not know the difference as I am still learning. Is there a way to convert the variable list and check if the list contains the generated random number then?

Comment: You don't check it with the list. You check it against one of the variables IN the list. At least, that is what the code in your question is trying to do.

Comment: So how would I go about number against each int in the string[]? Or do I have to do it individually?

Comment: You use a `foreach` loop, just like you are doing. You iterate the list and check one item at a time. The only problem your code has is that when it attempts to check one item, that item is a string, and the item it is checking against is an int. Either convert the string to an int or vice versa before you do your check.

Comment: I suspect strongly that you have multiple compile errors. The code you posted has extra closing brackets beyond what is listed to close the `foreach`. I'm guessing you have more errors than you think you do. Also, fix your errors from top to bottom -- errors earlier in the code can confuse the compiler and make it think there are errors that aren't really errors.

Comment: Actually my code is all working besides the code I posted for help on. That is just part of my thousand+ line code. By using a foreach loop how do I get the number to compare itself to my random int though? That's where I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfInts = List.Select(s => int.Parse(s));

if(listOfInts.Contains(test))
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Not sure what to elaborate on.  Use LINQ and int.parse to convert it to a list of integers, then use List.Contains to look for the target number.

Comment: There you go. Add that to your post. Explain to the OP what you're doing and why.

Comment: This converts the list to a bool though, and you can't mix bool and an int, so you can define this but I don't see how to really implement it?

Comment: It converts the list to a list of numbers, and then checks to see if the number you're looking for is in there.